# How can I unlock a large amount of files on isilon storage if a process had them open?

Tags: sql, isilon

Some background information :

- I have a couple SQL servers that have half their databases on isilon
  storage (I know, no bueno. I'm in the process of moving them).
- During the night one of those SQL servers suffered a BSOD and
  rebooted. Unfortunately the sql data files on the isilon were still
  considered open by the process. When SQL started up again it was
  unable to open these files since they were already open and locked by a nonexistent process.
- I was able to get them unlocked by using SSH to connect to the isilon
  and running 'isi_for_array "isi smb openfiles list" | grep -i mdf' in
  order to get the file name and the locking connection.
- Once I had this I executed 'isi smb openfiles close #ID#' to actually
  close the connection.

I've resolved the BSOD issue I had but I want to be a little proactive about the files on the isilon while they're still on the isilon. In the event this happens again how can I go about running the close command on all the files matching the list rather than executing it one at a time?

I'm hoping it's something simple that I'm not thinking of due to lack of sleep. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to serverfault.com! This sounds like a shell scripting problem to me.